# Filter in linq with ID's in a List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I need do a filter that request data with a parameter included in a list.

```
if (filter.Sc.Count > 0)
    socios.Where(s => filter.Sc.Contains(s.ScID));
```

I try on this way but this not work, I tried also...

```
socios.Where( s => filter.Sc.All(f => f == s.ScID));
```

How I can do a filter like this?

Comment: What type is your `Sc` member?

Comment: Is there any exception? May be you need to add `.ToList()`?

Comment: Add .ToList() in the end

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what do you mean? Do you mean it doesn't compile? Do you mean it throws an error? Do you mean it runs but doesn't actually filter as you want it to? Be more clear on exactly what the problem is and you are more likely to get a good answer that solves your problem. Also its probably worth telling us what the types involved are. Like what is `socios` (IEnumerable? IQueryable?) and what is `filter.Sc`...

Comment: Sc is a List<int>, I add .ToList after the if.

The result is all socios, and not only socios.ScID with in the Sc list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
socios.Where(s => filter.Sc.Contains(s.ScID));
```

*returns* a filtered query.  It does not *modify* the query.  You are ignoring the returned value.  You need something like:

```
socios = socios.Where(s => filter.Sc.Contains(s.ScID));
```

but depending on the type of `socios` the exact syntax may be different.

Comment: Good eye! Well spotted. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to needing to use the return value of your LINQ `.Where()`, you have a potential logic error in your second statement.  The equivalent logic for a `.Contains()` is checking if [*Any*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) of the elements pass the match criteria.  In your case, the second statement would be

```
var filteredSocios = socios.Where( s => filter.Sc.Any(f => f == s.ScID));
```

Of course if you can compare object-to-object directly, the `.Contains()` is still adequate as long as you remember to use the return value.